# iOS dismiss ViewController callback issue

Tags: ios

I have two UIViewControllers A and B.

```
[self presentViewController:B animated:YES completion:nil];
```

after I invoke `dismissViewController:` I need to have ability to invoke some method in the parent ViewController that have presented B ViewControlller. I thought `-viewWillAppear` method will be called but it does not work after dismiss.

Comment: Are they both in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you creating object of `B ViewController` then implement one custom `init` method something look like :

put this method in `B ViewController`

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withParentView:(UIViewController *)parentViewController
 {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.pViewController = parentViewController;
   // Custom code
}
return self;
```

}

When you created object of B View Controller then use above method and your **parentViewController** will be **self**.

And at a time of dismiss you cam call

```
[self.pViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best!!!

Comment: so, I have ability to do it using just self.parentViewController property and call viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to ask the "A" ViewController to dismiss the "B" ViewController (through a pointer to A ViewController) then in completion code do what you want.

iOS6 introduced a "rewind" function for view controller when you have A then B then C ViewController, you could, when C is presented, rewind to A.

look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581538/how-do-i-present-a-view-controller-and-dismiss-all-others)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller B subclass, create a property for controller A.

`@property (nonatomic, strong) ControllerA *controllerA;`

Before you present controller B, set the property:

`[controllerB setControllerA:self];`

When you dismiss controller B, use the completion block to call the method of controller A that you want to perform:

```
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.controllerA doSomething];
    }];
```

(One possible gotcha is that you'll end up with a retain cycle if controllerA is ever deallocated before controllerB.  If that's the case, you'd be better off setting controllerA as a delegate of controllerB and using an informal protocol)